# Detect when application is put into recents

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

On Tizen Wearable, there is a flow of a general application:

1. Application is started by user
2. Screen turns off (timeout without activity from user), `onPause` called
3. **Application is put into recents (when screen turns back on, application is not visible anymore)**

However there is another scenario:

1. Application is started by user
2. Screen turns off (timeout without activity from user), `onPause` called
3. Screen turns back on (activity from user): application is still visible, `onResume` called.

Is it possible to detect/know somehow if my application is not going to be visible after the screen turns back on?

`onPause` is unreliable, as it is called immediately after screen turns off. Is there any other signal/event I can register to detect if my application is really put into *kindof* background (recents list)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what '**Application is put into recents (when screen turns back on, application is not visible anymore)**' is?

As far as I know, after 20 seconds after screen turned off, the home-screen application will be located at the top of the window stack on the wearable device.
I think it's related to that. If it's not, please describe the scenario more details.

And, if you want to listen the events of the display state, please check the following API references:
https://samsung.github.io/TizenFX/latest/api/Tizen.System.Display.html
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/5.5/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__DEVICE__DISPLAY__MODULE.html

After the screen turns on, your application will be visible if it exists at the top of the window stack.

Comment: "Put into recents" is a bit misleading - sorry. What I'm looking for seems not available. As I just wanted to get notified once my application **will not be visible** if the screen turns back on. My application needs user's attention and when the screen times out I want to exit. But if the screen turns off, and my application is still on top (for 20minutes, or 1hour - configurable from settings on watch), I don't want to exit.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'getting notified once my application will not be visible if the screen turns back on" is too hard. How about checking screen state dim? As far as I know, when the screen times out, the screen will be dim state. And then, it'll go to off state. I think you can handle it using that. (In this case, your application will go to pause state when the screen turns off. You can handle the scenario using device API and checking application state if it's needed.)

Comment: Yes, I can handle that, but if the screen doesn't turn back on, I won't get any events :/

Comment: When the screen turns off, the application will be paused. The application doesn't know the window stack information directly.

Comment: I'm currently added a timer into onPause (in case display is off), and cancelling it in onResume. This works, but "showing last app" is a configurable setting and I'm not able to retrieve it (lack of documentation). You might know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963899/getting-system-settings-value

Answer (score 0):

You can get the display change event (such as LCD On/Off) when your application is visible as below.

```
static void _display_state_change_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *o, void *ev_info)
{
    Evas_Object *win = (Evas_Object*) data;
    Elm_Win_Aux_Message *msg = ev_info;
    const char *key, *val;

    key = elm_win_aux_msg_key_get(win, msg);
    val = elm_win_aux_msg_val_get(win, msg);
    if (!strcmp(key, "dpms_wm"))
    {
        if (!strcmp(val, "off"))
        {
            /* Display Off. Do Something */
        }
    }
}

...
evas_object_smart_callback_add(win, "aux,msg,received", _display_state_change_cb, win);
```

FYI, your application window doesn't get this message if it is not visible.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! This doesn't really helps, as I wanted to know when my application *will not be visible (onResumeD) after next screen turn on*. However I made a workaround which needs a tiny bit, if you could check that question too I'd appreciate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963899/getting-system-settings-value