# Getting system setting's value

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

How can I retrieve this setting's value from native C/C++ code (Tizen5.5)?

[image]

I need to know the current setting. Don't need any fancy subscribe to changes or similar. Just I want to retrieve the setting's current value. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, getting this value (Show last app) is not supported for 3rd party developers.

Comment: Thanks @Lunch. Please consider adding this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, getting this value (Show last app) is not supported for 3rd party developers.